# Quartz.NET hosted service xml jobs definition

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, quartz.net

I have a net6 web api and I'm tryng to add Quartz.NET3 as an hosted service, loading jobs and triggers from xml

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using NLog;
using NLog.Web;
using Quartz;
using Scheduler.API.Jobs;
using Scheduler.API.Model;
using System.Reflection;

//NLog configuration
var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Debug("init main");

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
}).UseNLog();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

//reading DB ConnectionString
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");

//Quartz configuration
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    // as of 3.3.2 this also injects scoped services (like EF DbContext) without problems
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

    q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
    {
        s.UseProperties = true;
        s.RetryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        s.UseSqlServer(sqlserver =>
        {
            sqlserver.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            // this is the default
            sqlserver.TablePrefix = "qrtz_";
        });
        s.UseJsonSerializer();
    });
    q.UseDefaultThreadPool(tp =>
    {
        tp.MaxConcurrency = 10;
    });
// also add XML configuration and poll it for changes
q.UseXmlSchedulingConfiguration(x =>
{
    x.Files = new[] { "quartz_jobs.xml" };
    x.ScanInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    x.FailOnFileNotFound = true;
    x.FailOnSchedulingError = true;
});
// Quartz.Extensions.Hosting allows you to fire background service that handles scheduler lifecycle
builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
{
    // when shutting down we want jobs to complete gracefully
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
    options.AwaitApplicationStarted = true;
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SchedulerDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "Scheduler API",
        Description = "Scheduler API di OneStore",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        {
            Name = "Example Contact",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/contact")
        },
        License = new OpenApiLicense
        {
            Name = "Example License",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license")
        }
    });

    var xmlFilename = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml");
    options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlFilename);
});


builder.Services.AddLogging();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

SchedulerDbContext context;

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

try
{
    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error(ex);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

and the following quartz_jobs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     version="2.0">

    <processing-directives>
        <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
    </processing-directives>

    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>TestJob</name>
            <group>TestGroup</group>
            <description>Test Job</description>
            <job-type>Scheduler.API.Jobs.DocumentHistoryCleanerJobe</job-type>
            <durable>false</durable>
            <recover>false</recover>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <simple>
                <name>TestTrigger</name>
                <group>TestGroup</group>
                <description>Test Trigger</description>
                <job-name>TestJob</job-name>
                <job-group>TestGroup</job-group>
                <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
                <repeat-interval>2000</repeat-interval>
            </simple>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

but nothing happens when the app starts.
I have already tried:

- changing the name of the file with one not existing give me a FileNotFoundException, meaning that Quartz is actively searching for it
- creating jobs & triggers from code, all works as expected

It seems like quartz is not having the startNow() call, but i don't understand where i have to put it.

Can someone help me figuring out the problem please?

Thanks

Comment: Quartz will activated after first request served with your project. because startup file will run after first request

Comment: could it be the typo in <job-type> DocumentHistoryCleanerJobe